# AngularJS - Cannot read property 'fieldName' of undefined when using $scope.formName.fieldName.$viewValue

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

We have a form on submission of which we show a modal dialog.  The modal also contains a form, whose values i am trying to retrieve.

I can get the value using ng-model, but in case of validation failure, it returns undefined.  In those cases I am trying to get the value by using $viewValue like

```
$scope.formName.fieldName.$viewValue
```

This works on the main page, but in the modal i am getting an error

```
Cannot read property 'fieldName' of undefined
```

i am using angular-ui-bootstrap for the modal.

jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/agadbnLr/2/

Why i am not able to get the field value in the modal using $viewValue, whereas it is possible to get the field value which directly in the page.